# How to print star character in mars mips

Tags: string, windows, character, system-calls, mips32

How to print star character in mars mips?
Use: li $v0, 11
What else to do need?

li $v0, 11 # syscall code 11
syscall

How to print a stellar spectrum from a file of 40 digits in a String .txt file
00100100234567000065432100007898700